# What might prevent a local area connection from obtaining DNS servers automatically?

Tags: windows-7, networking, dns, ethernet

until recently, I had been plugging into my school's through-the-wall ethernet connection just  fine. However, as of late, I have been connecting only to have it inform me that it has no internet access. After determining this was due to the DNS server not responding, I had to give it explicit instructions to use google's dns servers.

Is there anything that could be wrong on my end to cause this to happen? Is there any disadvantage to giving it explicit dns servers?

Thanks!
- Chase

Answer (score 3):

Your computer is obtaining the DNS servers just fine. The real problem is that those servers are down ("server not responding"), which you should report to the network admins.

Answer (score 0):

It could be your TCP/IP settings.  Does the school use static IPs for DNS servers, or do they provide them by DHCP?  If other people have proper service, check your TCP/IP settings against theirs and make the appropriate change.